# .format() in Python capabilities

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python and I ran across the following example, but I started tinkering with it because curiosity got the best of me.  There are really 2 related questions, and understanding them may help me understand what .format() actually does, and what the limitations are.  I've looked into the documentation, but my specific examples were never mentioned

I started fiddling with this code:

```
print 'The diameter of {planet} is {measure} kilometers'.format(planet="Earth", measure=12742.34)
```

which produced the output:

> The diameter of Earth is 12742.34 kilometers

But then I started to ask myself... "How flexible is this .format() thing?"

## Question 1

How do I avoid the rounding done by python when I choose {measure} to be a mathematical output?

```
print 'The diameter of {planet} is {measure}'.format(planet="Earth", measure=10/3)
```

> The diameter of Earth is **3** kilometers

## Question 2

How do I force the **float** of {measure}?
*psuedo* (I know it doesn't work, but placing here as a reference)

```
print 'The diameter of {planet} is {0:.2f}{measure}'.format(planet="Earth", measure=10/3)
```

Comment: `from __future__ import division`

Comment: This doesn't answer your questions, but is a great resource for understanding string formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to float by doing `measure = 10/ float(3)`. If the numerator or denominator is a float, then the result will be also.

and

In Python 3.x, the single slash (/) always means true (non-truncating) division. (The // operator is used for truncating division.) In Python 2.x (2.2 and above), you can get this same behaviour by putting  `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 1):

It means you are using python 2.x and you have many options because default integer division results in integer numbers

option 1: import the division library

```
from __future__ import division
```

option 2: change either of the factors to float or alternatively you can change 3 to float (decimal point) by ading .0 to it or you multiply by 1.0

```
print 'The diameter of {planet} is {measure:.2f}'.format(planet="Earth", measure=10/3.0)
```

Comment: Either way, note that `format` isn't involved; it's getting the *result* of the expression assigned to `measure`, not the expression itself.

Comment: yes the value of measure is already computed when it is fed to formatting.

Comment: I tried 'print 'The diameter of {planet} is {0:.2f}{measure}'.format(planet="Earth", measure=10/3.0)' but that gives me the following error:  IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: check it now, you used the positional index which makes the formatter to expect a tuple of three values , it has to be a named indexing using measure as key

Answer (score -1):

You could also just do:

```
print 'The diameter of {} is {}'.format("Earth",10/3)
```